# Reset Variable on function recall

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am programming a game where a game entity moves to a certain position on the HTML canvas. This position is a variable that can be only set the first time the function is called to avoid updating it. However, I want to be able to recalculate that variable for my player to move in another direction.

I've tried using a variable "i" for calculating the direction only on the first call to avoid recalculation in the update loop. Unfortunately, this stops me from recalculating the variable when I need another value

the vector "vec" is the position variable. "this.x" and "this.y" are the position coordinates of the game object.

```
this.moveRange = function(dis) {

    this.vec = new function(){this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * range); this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * range)}
    if(i == 0){
        distX   = this.vec.x - this.x
            distY   = this.vec.y - this.y

        dist    = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY)
        distX /= dist
        distY /= dist
    }
    i+= 1
    if(dist > 2){
        if(a < dis){
        this.x += (distX/100)*this.vel
        this.y += (distY/100)*this.vel
            a++
        }
    }
}
```